# Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported]

Tags: java, spring, rest, thymeleaf

I have two lists, one with user, the other with Team. I can select any user from the list, as well as any Team.
but can't add user to team. 
when you press the button, an error Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported]

Users

```
 @Entity
    @Table(name="users")
    public class Users {
        @Id
        @Column(name="email",/*unique = true,*/ nullable = false,length = 200)
        String email;         
        @Column(name="name",nullable = false,length = 200)
        String name;        
        @Column(name="password",nullable = false,length = 128)
        @JsonIgnore 
        String password;        
        @Column(name = "avatar", nullable = true)
        String avatar;            
        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name="team_id", nullable=true)
        Team team;
```

Team

```
Entity
@Table(name="team")
public class Team  {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
    Long id;        
    @Column
    String name;    
    @Column
    String url;    
    @Lob
    @Column(name = "avatar",nullable = true,columnDefinition="BLOB")
    String avatar;    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="team",cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JsonIgnore
    Set<Users> users = new HashSet<>();
```

AdminController

```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/admin/team/user}", method = RequestMethod.POST,
            produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE})
    public String addUserToTeam(@PathVariable String userName, @PathVariable String teamName,Model model, @ModelAttribute("userTeamForm") @Validated UserTeamForm userTeamForm,
            BindingResult result, final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
        Team team = teamRepository.findTeamByName(teamName).orElseThrow(() -> new NoSuchTeamException("Team not found"));
        Users user = userRpRepository.findUsersByName(userName)
                                     .orElseThrow(() -> new NoSuchUserException("User not found"));
        user.setTeam(team);
        userRpRepository.save(user);
        return "userTeam";
    }   
  @RequestMapping(value = "/admin", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String adminPage(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("userTeamForm",new UserTeamForm());
     ....
        return "admin";
    }
```

admin.html

```
  <form th:action="@{/admin/team/user/}"th:object="${userTeamForm}" method="POST">
                   <div class="form-group blu-margin">
                       <select class="form-control" id="addUser">
                           <option value="0">select user</option>
                           <option th:each="user : ${users}" th:value="${user.name}" th:text="${user.name}"></option>
                       </select>
                       <select class="form-control" id="addTeam">
                           <option value="0">select team</option>
                           <option th:each="team : ${teams}" th:value="${team.name}" th:text="${team.name}"></option>
                       </select>
                   </div>
                   <br/>
                   <input type="submit" value="Add User to Team" />
               </form>
```

UserTeamForm

Do I need to use UserTeamForm or can I directly work with Entity?

```
public class UserTeamForm {
            private String userName;        
        private String teamName;
    get/set
```

Comment: please share complete stack trace.

Comment: the fact is that this is the whole stack.
when you press the button, an error Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported]

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I didn’t notice  } in the method description.
I searched for a problem for two days))

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/team/user}", method = RequestMethod.POST,
```

there should not be }  after user